# Derivative of Analytic Function on Disc Bounded by Integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I am really stuck on a problem.

If we let $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$ be the set of holomorphic functions $f : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, then the problem states that there exists a constant $C$ so that $|$$f'(z)$$|$ $\leq C\int_{\mathbb{D}}|f(x+iy)|dxdy$ independent of $f \in \mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$ for all $z \in B = B_{\frac{1}{2}}(0)$, the closed ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ centered at $0$.  I don't think the specific radius is really relevant, though, as long as we pick something smaller than one.

If the integral is $0$ then $f$ is $0$, and if the integral is infinite then it's also trivial.  Let

$0 < \int_{\mathbb{D}}|f(x+iy)|dxdy = N < \infty$.

Then for a given $f$, using the Cauchy derivative estimate it follows pretty trivially that the constant $\frac{M_f}{N}$ works, for $M_f = 2$max$_{\partial B}|f(z)|$.  But this bound overshoots it on linear functions, admitting $\frac{M_f}{\pi}$, so I assume this is actually the best possible bound for a given $f$.

But I have no idea how to bound across $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$.  One method that I think was a waste of time was to try to prove that dilations are somehow the "worst".  But the inequalities that arise from trying to go this route aren't very tractable.

Can anyone help?  I'd be really appreciative.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By Cauchy's integral formula, 
$$
f'(z) = \frac1{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_r} \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^2} dw,$$
where $\gamma_r$ is a circle centered at 0, radius $r\geq 3/4$. 
By the change of variable $w=re^{i\theta}$, we have 
$$
f'(z)= \frac1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(re^{i\theta})}{(re^{i\theta}-z)^2} re^{i\theta} d\theta.$$
Using $|e^{i\theta}|\leq 1$ and $|w-z|\geq 1/4$, 
$$
|f'(z)|\leq \frac{16}{2\pi}  \int_0^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})| rd\theta.$$
Integrating over $r$ gives
$$\int_{3/4}^{7/8} |f'(z)| dr \leq \int_{3/4}^{7/8} \frac{8}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}  |f(re^{i\theta})|r d\theta  dr.$$
Then by the change of variable $x=r\cos \theta$, $y=r\sin \theta$, the desired inequality follows, 
$$|f'(z)|\leq \frac1{(7/8) - (3/4)} \cdot \frac8{\pi} \int_{D(3/4, 7/8)} |f(x+iy)| dxdy,$$
where $D(3/4, 7/8)$ is the annulus with inner circle radius $3/4$, outer one $7/8$.
Thus, we can take $$C= \frac1{(7/8) - (3/4)} \cdot \frac8{\pi}=\frac{64}{\pi}.$$